# How to use Linq to check for exact match?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var result = (from a in reference.AsEnumerable()
      from b in input.AsEnumerable()
      where a.Field<string>("Synonym(System name)") != null && b.Field<string>("SystemName") != null && a.Field<string>("Synonym(System name)").Contains(b.Field<string>("SystemName"))
      select  a.Field<string>("Standard Name")).Distinct();

        if (result.Any())
        {
      //this returns 
        }
```

Here in SystemName I have value like Image

`Synonym(System name)` contains value like `Image,Picture,ImgEditor`

So it works and all is well

but my issue is like if

`Synonym(System name`) contains value like `Pic,Picture,Image Editor`

This also returns true.But it should return false. because `Image` is not in `Pic,Picture,Image Editor`.

Comment: `Image` *is* in `Pic,Picture,Image Editor`.  Just not how you want it not to be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` is not `Image Editor`, but `Pic,Picture,Image Editor` **contains** `Image`. So try changing

```
a.Field<string>("Synonym(System name)").Contains(b.Field<string>("SystemName"))
```

With

```
a.Field<string>("Synonym(System name)").Split(',').Any( s => s == b.Field<string>("SystemName"))
```

**Why does this work?**

Your original logic has a single string `Pic,Picture,Image Editor`, and you try to check if `Image` exist inside it, and it surely does if you think of this as a string. Just as `c,Pic` is a part of the string. `String.Contains` have no concept of a list just because you have used comma as a delimiter inside the string.

The trick is therefore to use `string.Split(',')` to split the string into a string array by splitting on comma. The result of split is an array with the following values as seperate strings `["Pic","Picture","Image Editor"]`. We use the LINQ method `Any` on this to identify if any of the entries in this list is equal to the string `"Image"`, and since none of them are, it will return false.

Comment: If I change to equals it will be check for Image=Image,Picture,ImgEditor and it returns false where my result i need is true

Comment: the solution works but it would be more helpful that if you can explain how this split and any makes it to work?

Comment: $ᴀʀᴜn BᴇrtiL - No problem. I'll add an explanation now :)

Comment: wow...would have loved to give more points..but SO dont have such provision...:(